# Grail's Spring security: Use email instead of username to switch users in SwitchUserFilter

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have a modified User class in my spring security which use attribute email instead of username. Now I want to a functionality to switch users, so an admin can login seamlessly as a particular user without logging out. I came across this [Link](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/switchUser.html) , which shows there is a switchUserFilter to achieve this. So I tried to get it working by passing j_username as email,but it gets redirected to a blank page and the user does not switch.

I have tried all these things but still could not figure out a way around it:
1) Added to Config.groovy:
`grails.plugins.springsecurity.userLookup.usernamePropertyName='email`'

2) Create a method in User class getUserName() to return email.

P.S: I looked into the source code of springSecurity switchUserFilter([link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/switchuser/SwitchUserFilter.java#L209))and came across this code on line 209:

```
protected Authentication attemptSwitchUser(HttpServletRequest request)
        throws AuthenticationException {
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken targetUserRequest;

    String username = request.getParameter(usernameParameter);
```

But I am not sure if that is the issue and do not want to make changes in the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution: Add this to the config.groovy file

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.usernamePropertyName = 'email'
    grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSwitchUserFilter = true

    grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    ....
    '/j_spring_security_switch_user': ['ROLE_SWITCH_USER', 'isFullyAuthenticated()'],
    '/j_spring_security_exit_user': ['isFullyAuthenticated()'],
    '/public/**':              ['permitAll']
    .....
    ]
```

2) Then create a Role ROLE_SWITCH_USER in bootstrap.groovy

```
def switchUserRole = Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_SWITCH_USER') ?: new Role(authority: 'ROLE_SWITCH_USER').save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
```

And assign it to a super user

3) Then follow the instruction([here](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/switchUser.html)) to update the view to add a switch button

Answer (score 1):

The *usernameParameter* property of the SwitchUserFilter is set to *username* by default. That does seem to be part of your problem.

The SwitchUserFilter has a method named setUsernameParameter() that allows you to change this default. It seems the filter is a bean, so you might be able to do something like this in *grails-app/conf/spring/Config.groovy*

```
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.switchuser.SwitchUserFilter

beans = {
    switchUserFilter {
        usernameParameter = 'email'
    }
}
```

Or maybe something like this in grails-app/config/BootStrap.groovy

```
def switchUserFilter

def init = { servletContext ->
        switchUserFilter.usernameParameter = 'email'
}
```

Comment: It didn't work for me but I already found a solution to it and update it below. Appreciate you help.